# How do I use IndexedDB in a chrome extension?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which uses an IndexedDB. I'm using [idb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb) as a wrapper but I'm having errors when creating the initial object stores for the database. My code is as follows:

```
const DATABASE_NAME = 'PROCRASTINATE_BLOCKER_DATABASE';
const DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
const LINK_OBJECT_STORE = 'link';

setupData(): Promise<void> {
  return openDB(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION).then(db => {
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(LINK_OBJECT_STORE)) {
      db.createObjectStore(LINK_OBJECT_STORE,  { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    }
  });
}
```

I'm then called the `setupData()` method in the background.js when the extension gets installed:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  if(details.reason == 'install' || details.reason == 'update'){
    repositoryOperations.setupData().then(() => alert('stuff'));
  }
});
```

I also have "store" and "unlimited storage" in my manifest.json file, but honestly don't know if I need it or not.

When I run the extension in the browser I get the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': The database is not running a version change transaction.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb#indexeddb_documentation) and don't get what's wrong. If anybody could help me it would be amazing, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not following the example in that tutorial correctly: the code that creates the store should be inside a callback that is openDB's third parameter.

Comment: you're correct! I put the code there and it worked, thanks! I though it could be different because the openDB method returns a promise, and I would need to do the stuff after the promise was finished.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to change the code to the third argument on the openDB method, as wOxxOm suggested in the comment. In the end it looked like this:

```
setupData(): void {
  openDB(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, {
    upgrade(db) {
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(LINK_OBJECT_STORE)) {
        db.createObjectStore(LINK_OBJECT_STORE,  { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
      }
    }
  })
}
```